# In Flask and Bootstrap: How do I redirect a Modal embedded Form on submit to another Modal rather than a page on a url?

Tags: flask, redirect, modal-dialog, bootstrap-5

Ok, so this is my first ever question here. And also my first ever project, is a hobby so bear with me. I have a Flask app for recipe and Ingredients management. I have two forms one for a recipe another one to add new food items. The food items are listen on a drop down list o the Recipe form. if a food item is missing the user can then add a new food item. I managed to be able to have both forms in the same page and both working within a Modal from Bootstrap. Now, I want to be able to launch the Add missing Food Item from the Recipe Form, I can do that, but. after Adding a new Food Item my Modal is closed and the user is redirected to another page. In flask the return redirect(url_for(...html)) is doing that.